# Segmentation fault with pointers, arrays, and functions

Tags: c++

I'm not sure how to use my pointers properly.

I'm trying to return a intersection(an array with all the values 2 arrays have in common) and then print it out in another function.

I keep getting a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error and I'm not sure where I have memory issues.

```
int* intersect(int size1,int size2,int* arr1,int* arr2){
    int count=0;
    int newarr[size1+size2];
    int* intersectarr;

    for(int x=0;x<=size1;++x){
        for(int ix=0;ix<=size2;++ix){
            if(arr1[x]==arr2[ix]){
                newarr[count]==arr1[x];
                ++count;
            }
        }
    }
    intersectarr=new int[count];
    for(int x=0;x<count;++x)
        intersectarr[x]=newarr[x];

    delete[] newarr;
    return intersectarr;
}

void analysis(int size1,int size2,int *arr1,int *arr2){

     cout<<"Testing set operations!"<<endl;

    int* intersectarr=intersect(size1,size2,arr1,arr2);

    cout<<"Intersect: ";
    //outputarr((*(&intersectarr + 1) - intersectarr),intersectarr); //output array function
    cout<<endl;

}
```

Comment: `int newarr[size1+size2];` is not C++, since C++ does not have _variable length arrays_ (that's something the current C standard has).  For C++, should be a `std::vector`.

Comment: You call `delete` for `int newarr[size1+size2];` which is created on stack.

Comment: In inner `for-loop` you are using `newarr[count]==arr1[x];` for assignment instead of `newarr[count]=arr1[x];`